# How to insert Error_Message using EXECUTE sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using MS SQL Server I have the below code - it is being executed via a EXECUTE sp_executesql command:

```
Declare @Cmd nvarchar(max)
;with DistinctTables as
(
select distinct [DestTable], [SourceFile] from [tbl_IN_Ctrl_Dtl]
),
InsertCommands as
(
-- columns from Destination table
select *,
'BEGIN TRY insert into ' + [DestTable] + '(' +
STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + [DestCol]
        FROM [tbl_IN_Ctrl_Dtl] t1
        where t1.DestTable = drt.DestTable
        GROUP BY DestCol,ORDINAL_POSITION
        ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
+ ')' + 
' select ' + 
-- columns from source table
STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + [SourceCol]
        FROM [tbl_IN_Ctrl_Dtl] t1
        where t1.DestTable = drt.DestTable
        GROUP BY SourceCol,ORDINAL_POSITION
        ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
        + ' from ' + [SourceFile] 
        + '; 
        update tbl_IN_Ctrl_Header set ErrMsg = @@ERROR where SourceFile_INSERT = 0 and SourceFile = ''' + [SourceFile]+ '''' 
        +';
        update tbl_IN_Ctrl_Header set SourceFile_INSERT = 1 where SourceFile_INSERT = 0 and SourceFile = ''' + [SourceFile]+ '''' 
        +'; END TRY BEGIN CATCH'
        as InsertCommand
 from DistinctTables drt 
)
select @cmd = 
STUFF((
        SELECT ';' + char(10) + [InsertCommand]
        FROM InsertCommands
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
+';' from InsertCommands ic

--print @cmd

EXECUTE sp_executesql @cmd
```

I can retrieve the error number using line:

```
update tbl_IN_Ctrl_Header set ErrMsg = @@ERROR where SourceFile_INSERT = 0 and SourceFile = ''' + [SourceFile]+ ''''
```

However, how do I retrieve the actual text error message?  If I use ERROR_MESSAGE I just get Null.  How do I modify the above to update 'ErrMsg' to the actual text error message?  I've put a BEGIN TRY at the beginning of the Insert and END TRY at the end of the UPDATE but I now receive the error Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: You need to provide a little bit of context here. Why are you just randomly assuming there is an error?

Comment: You'll need to wrap the `INSERT` in a `TRY` block and perform the update in a `CATCH` block, where `ERROR_MESSAGE()` will contain the error text.

Comment: @SeanLange it forms part of an ETL process so they can be errors -these files are from a 3rd party

Comment: @DanGuzman how do I do that?

Comment: Do I need a BEGIN TRANSACTION as well?

Comment: @Michael, see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql) for the `CATCH` block syntax and example.

Comment: @DanGuzman thank you